# AZURE github actions receiving a 404 error upon successful deployment

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, http-status-code-404

it is my project. https://github.com/Andriy0660/hello
why after a successful deployment using azure github actions I get a 404, all ip addresses are allowed, public access is allowed, the url I write is correct

I created a simple program for testing deployment, added some maven plugins (available on github), created azure app services, changed the secret key of the publish profile, successfully deployed, go to https://helloprogram.azurewebsites.net/hello and get a 404, maybe additional settings are needed, maybe someone knows Azure and can tell me, or try to deploy my mini program and tell me what the reason was, or recommend another service in which it will be easier, in which you can use a student subscription

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

***I have tried to deploy your application using GitHub actions.***

When I was deploying your code,  I found that there is no mapping for `/hello` path in the code. Instead of `/hello` you have mapped `GetMapping` with only `/` path.

**Code Snippet:**

```java
package com.example.testserver;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hello(){
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

To access your application, you have to try with `/` mapping after the URL like below:
`https://helloprogram.azurewebsites.net/`

**Response:**

*I'm able to hit the API of your application as shown below:*

[image]